# Getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') when i try to fetch data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have a react frontend and when i try to get data from my node js backend but my api seems to be in order

```
const SingleProductPage = () => {

  const { productId } = useParams();

  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/Product/${productId}`);
      setProduct(data);
    };
    fetchProduct();
  }, [productId]);

  if (!product) {
    return <Error errorMessage="Sorry, Product not found!" />;
  }


  return (
        <div className="single-slider-div">
          <Splide>
            {product.src.map((src, index) => (
              <SplideSlide>
                <img key={index} src={src} alt="product img" />
              </SplideSlide>
            ))}
          </Splide>
        </div>
      
  );
};

export default SingleProductPage;
```

I tried setting an object as the initial state for product but it returns the same error, i tried testing the backend route and it works fine. I have added relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the data being fetched, use `console.log` before setting the prdocut? Also, _setting an object as the initial state for product_ , use `null` or update the condition to `Object.keys(product).length` instead, otherwise the error message will never get run

Comment: You are checking `product` so the product exists. The issue is `product.src` which seems to be undefined. You need to check that.

Answer (score 1):

Add a conditional check for `product` and `product.src` in your return statement. Also add `key={index}` to the `SplideSlide` component.

```
return (
    <div className="single-slider-div">
        <Splide>
            {product && product.src && product.src.map((src, index) => (
                <SplideSlide key={index}>
                    <img src={src} alt="product img" />
                </SplideSlide>
            ))}
        </Splide>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to access the product.src before the component is rendered and hence the undefined value error. You can refactor the code as follows ->

```
const SingleProductPage = () => {
  const { productId } = useParams();
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/Product/${productId}`);
        setProduct(data);
      } catch (error) {
        //? Error handling
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    fetchProduct();
  }, [productId]);

// changed the if statement to factor in the product.src
  if (!product || !product.src) {
    return <Error errorMessage="Sorry, Product not found!" />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="single-slider-div">
      <Splide>
        {product.src.map((src, index) => (

// defining key prop here
          <SplideSlide key={index}>
            <img src={src} alt="product" />
          </SplideSlide>
        ))}
      </Splide>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SingleProductPage;
```

In addition, I also moved the key prop up to the "SplideSlide" component as it is best practice to define the key prop at the outermost element when mapping over an array as mentioned [here](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) in React docs.